# System Cannot find the file nmake cmake error with Mingw

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw

When building with cmake on windows using Mingw64 we get errors like:

`System cannot find the file specified`

Log:

```
$ cmake ..
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:72 (project):
  Running

   'nmake' '-?'

  failed with:

   The system cannot find the file specified


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/MyTools/C/libs_download/cpp-httplib-0.11.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The **first error message** is searched relatively easy. It means that CMake attempts to use `NMake Makefiles` generator but there is no `nmake` installed in your system. That is, you need to choose another generator (or install nmake).

Comment: Yes, I figured it out :P I basically answered my own question.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because cmake uses the Microsoft CMake format as default. The `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set` here also indicates that we need to set the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` variable to a `c++` compiler path.

To fix we need to use the following command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_CC_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=mingw32-make -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

Here we provide the following flags:

- `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++` - Use `g++` as C++ compiler (or provide full path)
- `CMAKE_CC_COMPILER=gcc` - Use `gcc` as C compiler
- `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=mingw32-make` - Use `mingw32-make` as the make program
- `-G "MinGW Makefiles"` - Use the MinGW Makefile format not Microsoft makefile format

After this you can run `mingw32-make` as usual instead of `make` to build :)

Comment: I just recently started coding in C++ after years of struggling to get a working project setup on Windows using mingw32-make and Eclipse, and this just helped me build a required library in the graphics book I'm following along in. Thanks so much!
It seems like most everything expects you to be using Visual Studio too ...